# How to retrieve a shard ID of DynamoDB in Lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

*AWS DynamoDB Triggers* enable us to capture all changes in our DynamoDB table. Lambda assigns each Lambda function to [a shard of DynamoDB Streams](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/realtime-data-processing-with-amazon-dynamodb-streams-and-aws-lambda-7302015/22).

I want to retrieve a shard ID in Lambda function to keep consistency in some data processing tasks, but I can't find the way to get it. Does any one manage to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Lambda abstracts the details of shard processing and serialization away from you. The only way to process a stream and be aware of the shard ID at the same time is to consume the stream yourself using the KCL and the DynamoDB Streams adapter.